# Understanding an equality in the paper "Class groups, totally positive units, and squares"

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

[image]

This is an excerpt from the paper ["Class groups, totally positive units, and squares"](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-01/S0002-9939-1986-0848870-X/S0002-9939-1986-0848870-X.pdf) (page 36). I am struggling to understand the last equality $|K^{(1)}_{2}:K|=|\overline{O}_K^{+}|$, the bar convention means modulo squares. In particular, I do not see why $|\overline{O}_K^{+}|$ should be finite.

Comment: Surely that O should be a U.

Comment: That's my thoughts too, especially if you consider the statement that $O^+_K$ is a subgroup. However, $U_K$ was considered in the paper previously, and just below in the proof it states: "By the self-duality established above, we may use exactly the same reasoning as
used by Taylor on $\overline{U}^+_K$ and $\overline{U}^0_K$ in [11, (*), p. 157] to establish $\overline{O}^+_K\cong \overline{O}^0_K$".